# How can I return a file from a path in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

I'm trying to get a file from an absolute path saved in a MySQL database.
The idea is to get the file from a string param and return and use it in the frontend.
The backend is made in java with Spring Boot and JPA.

The main problem is that I don't find a way to get the file or the bytes of the file. In this code, the method returns the path, not the file in this path.

The method to get the files is the next (doesn't work):

```
public File getPic(String filename) throws IOException {
    Path currentWorkingDir = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();      
    File file = new File(currentWorkingDir.normalize().toString()+ "\\src\\main\\resources\\userprofileimages\\" + filename);
    return file;
}
```

The method to save the file in the project is the next (it works):

```
public UserEntity uploadProfile(Long id, MultipartFile file) {
    if (file == null || !file.getContentType().contains("image")) {
        throw new ProfileImageException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Este archivo no es una imagen.");
    }
        
    UserEntity user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotExistException (HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "El usuario no existe."));;
    try {
        Path currentWorkingDir = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();

        if (user.getProfilepic() == null) {
            File oldpic = new File(currentWorkingDir.normalize().toString() + "\\src\\main\\resources\\userprofileimages\\" + user.getProfilepic());
            oldpic.deleteOnExit();
        }
            
        String filename = user.getId() + "." + file.getOriginalFilename().substring(file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        File path = new File(currentWorkingDir.normalize().toString() + "\\src\\main\\resources\\userprofileimages\\" + filename);

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);
        output.write(file.getBytes());
        output.close();
            
        user.setProfilepic(filename);
        return userRepository.save(user);
            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ProfileImageException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "La imagen no se a podido guardar correctamente.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working with your current solution? Are you getting an exception? If yes, which one, on what line? Or are you getting an unexpected output? Can you make the code smaller to isolate the problem you're getting (and let us reproduce it)? E.g. if UserEntity is not needed for the problem, strip it out, simplify until your problem reproduces in 3-5 lines of code with a clear exception. When that happens it tends to be trivial to google / guess the issue.

Comment: @PetrJaneček I'm getting an unexpected output. The output is the URL which I introduce to get the file. I have been searching for a solution but I find nothing.

Comment: The getPic() method is returning "an abstract representation of file and directory pathnames". Not the content of the file (picture).

Comment: `src/main/resources` will not be there when you deploy. Anything in `src` will not be there unless you configure your deployment to include it. All those files will get put into the same location as your classes when the project is built. For files in `src/main/resources` they will become  resources that you should read from the class path using something like `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/userprofileimages/file")`